# 3D plot from an array

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have an array on the following form:

```
Array[1, {4, 4, 3}];
```

and i want to visualise the data in 3D plot, i tried many times but usually Mathematica reply that there is an error.

here is a part of the code

```
 NNN = 4;
curvesV = Array[1, {NNN, NNN, 3}];
(*curvesOC=Array[l,{1001,13}];*)
\[Tau] = T;
For[l = 1, l <= NNN, l++,
 {V = l - 1;
  For[ll = 1, ll <= NNN, ll++,
   {Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], c] = ll - 1;
    curvesV[[l, ll, 1]] = V;
    curvesV[[l, ll, 2]] = Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], c];
    (*Print[curvesV[[l,ll,1]]];
    Print[curvesV[[l,ll,2]]];*)
    
    Sol[t_] = 
     NDSolve[Eq, A, {t, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> 10^7, AccuracyGoal ->10];
    Subscript[\[CapitalRho], 66] = 
     Abs[\[Rho][6][6][\[Tau]]] /. Sol[\[Tau]];
    curvesV[[l, ll, 3]] = Abs[Subscript[\[CapitalRho], 66]]^2;
    }]}]
curvesV
DRF = Flatten[curvesV, 1];
ListPlot3D[curvesV]
ListSliceContourPlot3D[curvesV]
ListContourPlot3D[curvesV]
ListPlot3D[DRF]
ListSliceContourPlot3D[DRF]
ListContourPlot3D[DRF]
```

part of the data

```
{{{0, 0, {0.20667}}, {0, 1, {0.584291}}, {0, 2, {0.948858}}, {0,3, {0.922532}}}, {{1, 0, {0.20667}}, {1, 1, {0.188105}}, {1,2, {0.000314782}}, {1, 3, {0.163525}}}, {{2, 0, {0.20667}}, {2,1, {0.948938}}, {2, 2, {0.0784778}}, {2, 3, {0.00361825}}}, {{3,0, {0.20667}}, {3, 1, {0.772576}}, {3, 2, {0.466603}}, {3,3, {0.00774734}}}}
```

Comment: i tried to flatten the array and plot but also still there is an error.

Comment: `ListPlot3D[RandomReal[1, {20, 20}]]` ?

Comment: i added part of the code.

Comment: Can you please add the code in an easy to copy-and-paste format? As in, type it out? This would be a better method to share snippets of your code than posting a picture. That said, the dimensions of your data are not such that they can be plotted without adjusting said dimensions.

Comment: unfortunately the code is very big. I added the related part from the code. and a sample of the output array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

```
data = {{{0, 0, {0.20667}}, {0, 1, {0.584291}}, {0, 
     2, {0.948858}}, {0, 3, {0.922532}}}, {{1, 0, {0.20667}}, {1, 
     1, {0.188105}}, {1, 2, {0.000314782}}, {1, 3, {0.163525}}}, {{2, 
     0, {0.20667}}, {2, 1, {0.948938}}, {2, 2, {0.0784778}}, {2, 
     3, {0.00361825}}}, {{3, 0, {0.20667}}, {3, 1, {0.772576}}, {3, 
     2, {0.466603}}, {3, 3, {0.00774734}}}};
newdata = Flatten /@ Flatten[data, 1]
ListPlot3D[newdata]
```

[image]

**Original**

Depend on the structure of your data. Maybe this

```
data = RandomReal[1, {20, 20, 3}]; 
ListSliceContourPlot3D[data]
ListContourPlot3D[data]
```

Comment: i added part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a data structure appearing in [`RGBColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RGBColor.html)

```
Graphics[{Pink, Disk[{100, 100}, 40], 
  Raster[RandomReal[1, {200, 200, 4}], ColorFunction -> RGBColor]}]
```

[image: Raster]

And in [Raster3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster3D.html):

```
Graphics3D[{Raster3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5}]]}]
```

[image: Graphics3D[{Raster3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5}]]}]]

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Raster3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5, 3}]]}]
```

[image: Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Raster3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5, 3}]]}]]

I am sorry Your code snippet is incomplete and can not run successful.

```
Head@curvesV
```

(* List *)

```
Head /@ curvesV
```

(* {List, List, List, List} *)

Dimensions@curvesV
(* {4, 4, 3}  *)

```
First@curvesV
```

(* {{0, 0, Abs[
Abs[[Rho][6][6][T]] /.
NDSolve[Eq, A, {T, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> 10000000,
AccuracyGoal -> 10]]^2}, {0, 1,
Abs[Abs[[Rho][6][6][T]] /.
NDSolve[Eq, A, {T, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> 10000000,
AccuracyGoal -> 10]]^2}, {0, 2,
Abs[Abs[[Rho][6][6][T]] /.
NDSolve[Eq, A, {T, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> 10000000,
AccuracyGoal -> 10]]^2}, {0, 3,
Abs[Abs[[Rho][6][6][T]] /.
NDSolve[Eq, A, {T, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> 10000000,
AccuracyGoal -> 10]]^2}} *)

```
First@Array[1, {4, 4, 3}]
{{1[1, 1, 1], 1[1, 1, 2], 1[1, 1, 3]}, {1[1, 2, 1], 1[1, 2, 2], 
  1[1, 2, 3]}, {1[1, 3, 1], 1[1, 3, 2], 1[1, 3, 3]}, {1[1, 4, 1], 
  1[1, 4, 2], 1[1, 4, 3]}}

Graphics[{Pink, Disk[{100, 100}, 40], 
  Raster[Array[1, {200, 200, 4}], ColorFunction -> RGBColor]}]
```

fails because it expects more values than only 1s.

This works because of the attributes of the evaluation of the representation built-ins.